# How to display leading zero for minutes from excel time format cell?

Tags: excel

I have the format 10:05 in cell A1. 
I know that with the usage of the minute() function I can get the minutes but if I write the MINUTE(A1) it returns me 5 and not 05.
So what is the best way to get the hour and the minutes including the leading zero?

```
HOUR(A1) = 10
MINUTE(A1) = 5 (but I want 05)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the cell value to always contain 2 digit minutes,

```
=RIGHT("0" & MINUTE(A1),2)
```

will do it

Alternatively if you are happy for the value to be `5` but just want to display `05` you can format the cell to show leading zeros:

In the cell containing `=MINUTE(A1)` , edit the format (CTRL+1 pc, CMD+1 mac)
and select a custom format of `00`

Comment: thanks a lot. The second solution with the custom format of 00 works fine!!

Comment: This will convert the number into text - `=RIGHT("0" & MINUTE("10:05:00"),2)*2` will return 10, but `=ISNUMBER(RIGHT("0" & MINUTE("10:05:00"),2))` will return `FALSE`.  Keep it in mind if you need to use `MATCH` or `VLOOKUP` type formula against the number. Formatting the number will keep it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

1.Right Click on Result Cell

2.Click Format Cell

3.Choose Custom on Left Tab

4.Select 0

5.Type Two 00 in Text box above selections

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgRXz.jpg)